How to prevent the resizing of an element's bounding box in Safari?
I have a bunch of <use> (combined with <symbol>) elements within an SVG that I indefinitely animate using translate. This works really well on every browser. The thing is, this SVG is rotated. The rotation of the SVG causes the bounding box of the <use> elements to constantly change dimensions as they're animated - this does only happen in Safari and any iOS browser. This change in dimensions causes highly frequent layout repaints of the ENTIRE document, which obviously leads to very poor performance of the website. I have tried MANY things to resolve this issue:

Animating the elements using CSS Keyframes, Javascript web animation API, SVG <animate> and <animateTransform> - all with the same results, and in combination with the following:
Put will-change: transform;, contain: strict;, isolation: isolate; and even will-change: width, height; on the elements in question and their parent element(s)
Tried all kinds of other CSS properties on different elements:

Variations of height, width in px, vw and %
Variations of position between fixed, absolute and the default static
...and more.



No matter what I do, the simple translation of the elements alter the size of their bounding box which causes layout repaints. A few noteworthy things:

In Chrome / Edge / Firefox, the bounding box is rounded to 2 decimal places and does not change, however in Safari this is 0 decimal places and flickers back and forth between 2 values.
Current solution is to use the transform SVG attribute on the parent SVG element to rotate everything, which also doesn't work in Safari. The animations work smoothly on all browsers now, but there is no rotation in Safari.

Does anyone have an idea of what I can do, to prevent the bounding box from resizing after rotating (while animating)? It seems like the bounding box is measuring the element's size on a non-rotated plane (i.e. just the regular x and y).
EDIT: Here is a code snippet to reproduce it in your own browser:


  @keyframes move {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    50% {
      transform: translateX(400px);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
  }

  rect {
    animation: move linear infinite 10s;
  }
<svg width="500px" height="100px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100px" height="100px"></rect>
</svg>



If you inspect the rectangle in Safari and look at its bounding box, you will see that its dimensions rapidly flash between 2 values. Example of the code snippet above, recorded in Safari 18.0.1 for Mac:

This is a super simple example, but it's the changing of dimensions that causes the entire document to have its entire layout recalculated. This is very expensive and causes a laggy website if it has a bit more content. That's why I'm wondering if there's a way to prevent this behaviour.
If you can't reproduce the example in Safari, try zooming in and out on the rectangle.
Earlier in my question I mentioned that the rotate is the cause, but as you can see, this also happens without rotate.
Any help would be appreciated!

Report webkit issues to its bugtracker

Please add a minimal reproducible example. It's impossible to suggest a workaround without a running snippet. In short, WebKit is currently (2024) clearly behind (compared to Firefox and Chromium/blink) when it comes to SVG capabilities - especially animations. As often mentioned by @Robert Longson: `' instances put a significant extra load on the renderer, so explicit copies of your geometry elements are preferable (since SVG/markup is usually served gzipped - the redundant code won't significantly affect load times).

@herrstrietzel I just added a super simple code example and a gif. I really hope the problem is clear

I wouldn't focus on the resizing of the bounding box. That's a red herring and is a perfectly valid thing to do. The repaint of the entire document is the bug. Moving a single SVG element shouldn't cause that because SVG doesn't need to reflow.

@RobertLongson it's really confusing, because the repainting of the entire document happens anyways (despite trying to separate the svg as described in my post). In my specific case, the slight rotation of the SVG causes a crazy degradation in performance (repaints happen way less frequently / lag). I know that correlation doesn't imply causation, but the only difference I see is the more frequent changes of the dimensions of the bounding box of SVG elements after rotating the <svg>.
